# Accessing class Objects methods passed in parameter (Java)

Tags: java

Assuming an object of class test was passed into this equals function, how do i access the methods associated with the obj object? I've tried using `getClass()`, and also trying to clone the obj, but nothing seems to work.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine what the class is and cast it to the correct class.  That will allow you to access the methods/attributes of the passed in class.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use `instanceof` and cast the object.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
   if (obj instanceof Test){
      Test t = (Test)obj;
      t.myMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!